# How do i add client side js libraries in Nuxt>

Tags: nuxt.js, baqend

First time on nuxt. i am trying to add a client side library.

In a normal html i will just add it to my index.html file. But i have no idea how do i do the same on nuxt.

How do i add it?

this is my config

```
module.exports = {

  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: 'digglu',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'social media site' },
      { name: 'google-signin-client_id', content:'xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },
  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#3B8070' },
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    /*
    ** Run ESLINT on save
    */
    extend (config, ctx) {
      if (ctx.dev && ctx.isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to NuxtJS documentation: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins

I can confirm this works, but some plugins still throw error on the first 3 refreshes of the page, then the error is gone, I don't know the reason.

> **Client-side only**
>
> Some plugins might work only for the browser, you can use the ssr:
>   false option in plugins to run the file only on the client-side.
>
> Example:
>
> nuxt.config.js:
>
> ```
> module.exports = {
>   plugins: [
>     { src: '~/plugins/vue-notifications', ssr: false }
>   ]
> }
> ```
>
> plugins/vue-notifications.js:
>
> ```
> import Vue from 'vue'
> import VueNotifications from 'vue-notifications'
>
> Vue.use(VueNotifications)
> ```
>
> In case you need to require some libraries only for the server, you
>   can use the process.server variable set to true when webpack is
>   creating the server.bundle.js file.

Comment: how to do it if you are not importing Vue packages? Example paho-mqtt package which works only in browser

Answer (score 2):

According to the Nuxt documentation you can use a naming convention or object syntax for that in your `nuxt.config.js`.

#### Naming Convention

```js
export default {
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/foo.client.js', // only in client side
    '~/plugins/bar.server.js', // only in server side
    '~/plugins/baz.js' // both client & server
  ]
}
```

#### Object Syntax

```js
export default {
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/both-sides.js' },
    { src: '~/plugins/client-only.js', mode: 'client' }, // only on client side
    { src: '~/plugins/server-only.js', mode: 'server' } // only on server side
  ]
}
```

See here: https://nuxtjs.org/guides/directory-structure/plugins#client-or-server-side-only